# Memoization vs Lazy initialization/evaluation

Tags: ruby

What is the exact difference between `Memoization` and `lazy initialization` technique.

Example with respect to ruby would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Memoization is saving the result of a long execution in order to not repeat it once called again.

An example for memoization:

```
class A
  def initialize
  end

  def do_some_long_calculation
    @do_some_long_calculation ||= my_calc_here
  end
end
```

It means that once we call `do_some_long_calculation` the result would be saved to `@do_some_long_calculation` and subsequent calls won't trigger the `my_calc_here` method.

Lazy initialization is making this long execution only when needed and not when initializing the object.

Actually the first code example also demonstrates lazy initialization.
A non lazy initialization version would look like:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @do_some_long_calculation = my_calc_here
  end

  def do_some_long_calculation 
    @do_some_long_calculation 
  end
end
```

As you can see, here we do the lengthy calculation immediately on the init of class A, whereas in the first example we only do the calculation when the exact method is called.

The long calculation is still done only once, but on the initialization of the class and not when explicitly called.